# Getting predicted values from autoKrige

Tags: r, data-structures, kriging, automap

I've just performed kriging on my spatial data using the `autoKrige`function from the `automap` package. However, I am now struggling to get the fitted values.

I can simply execute `plot(kriging_results)` and see the map, but I want to make some changes and would like to work directly on the fitted values.

I've been exploring a bit the `autoKrige` class, unsuccessfully. Can I get some help from you?

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it!

`resultados_kriging$krige_output@data$var1.pred` despite looking like a weird detail, returns exactly what I'm looking for